# Please install mysql adapter 'gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter'

Tags: mysql, mysql2

I'm having trouble finding a solution to this problem. I'm getting the error:

````
Please install the mysql adapter: 'gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter'

 /Users/ Andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:143:in `block in replace_gem': Please install the mysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter` (mysql is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:48:in `resolve_hash_connection'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:39:in `resolve_string_connection'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:23:in `spec'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:127:in `establish_connection'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `on_load'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/ Andy /config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/ Andy /config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/ Andy /config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /Users/ Andy /config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /Users/ Andy/mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/ Andy /mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>' ```
````

Here is the `gem env` output.

```
  RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.15
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/ Andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/ Andy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/ Andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/ Andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
     - /Users/ Andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

If I can provide any more information please let me know.

Thanks,
-Andy

---

P.s - My `database.yaml` already has `mysql2`.

Comment: So uh...  Have you tried installing the gem it says you need?

Comment: I did try and it give me this error 

ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-mysql-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter, activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter, activerecord-jdbc-adapter, activerecord-odbc-adapter, activerecord-nulldb-adapter

Answer (score 114):

The problem is on your file config/database.yml

You should have a line that specify that the adapter is mysql2 (and not mysql)

```
adapter: mysql2
```

Instead of

```
adapter: mysql
```

Answer (score 17):

What helped for me was specifying adapter mysql2 instead of mysql (note the digit!) in config/database.yml.

Answer (score 10):

1) You need to update your `config/database.yml` file and change:

```
adapter: mysql
```

into

```
adapter: mysql2
```

2) You need to update your `Gemfile` and explicitly add `activerecord-mysql2-adapter` dependency there:

```
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'activerecord-mysql2-adapter'
```

Answer (score 9):

I never would have believed it but deleting my database.yml file and recreating it actually solved the problem for me too.  Thanks Tyler.  I spent hours installing and uninstalling different versions of the gems mysql, mysql2, activerecord-mysql-adapter, etc...  In the end, my gemfile has

```
gem 'mysql2', "~>0.3.11"
```

and my database.yml file has

```
adapter: mysql2
```

I am on OSX 10.8, rails 3.2.8, and ruby 1.9.3.

By the way, I experienced the same issues with the mysql2 adapter on my Windows 7 machine.  Uninstalling and even deleting the directory for the activerecord-mysql-adapter gem seemed to be critical as well.

Comment: that mysql2 version ~>0.3.11 really saves me

Answer (score 6):

You want to install the [`mysql2` gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2).

Really, you should probably add it to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem "mysql2"
```

And then install your gems with bundler:

```
bundle install
```

Comment: gem `mysql2` is already installed and i have it in my `gemfile` and i also did bundle the error is after all this

Comment: @eml @andy  What do you have set for your adapter?  It should also be `mysql2`, not `mysql`.

Comment: @galador mysql2. Seems like the problem was something else though as it is working now. For some reason. :)

Comment: worked with gem "mysql" . My configured database in database.yml is also "mysql" btw

Comment: In my case, same error as OP was absolutely due to having "mysql" instead of "mysql2" as the adapter in my database.yml

Comment: Had the same issue. Solved by changing in config/database.yml the adapter from "mysql" to "mysql2"

Answer (score 6):

This might be late but bundle install was installing **0.4.0** So I tried to edit the **gem file** and I replace `mysql2` with

`gem 'mysql2', "~>0.3.11"`

and then

`bundle install`

in the terminal (This will install **mysql2 0.3.11** and not the last version) I think active record have problems working with the last version. Well I hope it helps

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1.** `gem 'mysql2', "~>0.3.11"` instead of `gem 'mysql2'` in Gemfile

**Step 2.** putting `mysqllib.dll` (available at mysql installation `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\lib` ) in the `C:\ruby2.0.0\bin` folder solved the rake `db:migrate` problem and successfully connected my rails with mysql (`database.yml` contains mysql2)

*I'm running windows 7, 64bit, mysql 64bit, ruby 2.0.0 [x64-mingw32]*

Thanks you all for your inputs.

Comment: Is this an answer to the original question or a response to other answers?  If the latter it should be a comment.

Comment: When I ran the command `bin/rails generate rspec:install`, I got the error message `Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add \`gem 'mysql2'\` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).` This happened when I did not have a version specification for the `mysql2` gem, and also when I specified its version as `~> 0.4`. Your Step 1 (and running `bundle install` after editing `Gemfile`, of course) fixed the problem for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as OP on OSX Lion after upgrading to Rails 3.2. Removing all gems, bundle install, etc did not work. Gemfile and database.yml were correctly specifying mysql2.

In the end, I deleted and recreated my database.yml and everything works again. It was probably a typo or hidden character in the file.

Answer (score 3):

If nothing helps (you have `mysql2` as adapter in your `database.yml`) and you are using **RVM** to manage your ruby versions, here is the simplest solution:

Try to **remove** all of your old gemsets (including `global`), install a fresh ruby version and bundle again. I could solve the problem that way.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you have changed adapter to mysql2 for a certain environment only but are not passing the environment to the rake command.

E.g. I only changed mysql to mysql2 on the production environment but was running

```
rake generate_secret_token
```

when I changed it to the following it worked:

```
rake generate_secret_token RAILS_ENV=production
```

Answer (score 2):

you have mentioned your database.yaml file already has `mysql2`.

Its worth checking if you have `activerecord-mysql2-adapter` installed.
(Note `-mysql2-` )

Answer (score 1):

I would say that change the commented information on top in database.yml to

```
# 
# Install the MYSQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
```

second: add  " gem 'mysql2' " (what ever is inside the double quotation marks) to gemfile .

save everything, do bundle install. Hope that helps.

or it just could be a typo.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue and getting same error when run command

```
gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter
```

you need to install **libmysqlclient-dev**

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when I also got this error:

> rake aborted!
>   Please install the mysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter` (mysql is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)

After I searched Google and tried many ways, it didn't work. Finally, the answer is

- Navigate to the root of your app, run `open gemfile`
- Add the line `gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3.7'` directly below the gem line for rails.

Answer (score 0):

For a old rails 2.3.18 ruby 1.8.7 app that I 'migrated' to a new MacBook (High Sierra - 10.13.6), in order to get the app to run (using POW) and to use script/console, I had to disable SIP and create a link to a file in /urs/lib/ directory. Migration Assistant was unable to create the link because of SIP.

To Disable SIP - System Integrity Protection

1. Boot into Mac OS Recovery Mode as usual by holding down the Command and R keys during system start.
2. Choose the language as usual (if applicable)
3. At the “MacOS Utilities” screen, pull down the “Utilities” menu from the top of the screen.
4. In terminal, type command: csrutil disable
5. Restart your computer

Finally, after restarting, in Terminal enter this command:

sudo ln /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib

Answer (score -2):

I just added the following line to my Gemfile an it worked:

gem "mysql"

Before:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "rails", "3.2.16"
gem "jquery-rails", "~> 2.0.2"
gem "coderay", "~> 1.1.0"
gem "fastercsv", "~> 1.5.0", :platforms => [:mri_18, :mingw_18, :jruby]
gem "builder", "3.0.0"
...
```

After:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "mysql"
gem "rails", "3.2.16"
gem "jquery-rails", "~> 2.0.2"
gem "coderay", "~> 1.1.0"
gem "fastercsv", "~> 1.5.0", :platforms => [:mri_18, :mingw_18, :jruby]
gem "builder", "3.0.0"
...
```

Comment: This will downgrade your mysql gem from `mysql2` into `mysql`. Don't do it. You should be on `mysql2`.