# mysql2 adapter issue: libruby.so.1.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, redmine, mysql2

I note that there have been many other similar questions, but my context seems to be different.

**Error**

The following is the error I am getting, trying to run/restart a Rails Application (Redmine).  Redmine was running fine, but there have been some server updates by the shared host, thus seeing these problems.

*mysql2 is listed in the gem/bundle list.  mysql2.so exists in the location it is looking for, and has the required (executable) permissions.  Thank you any suggestions in addressing this issue.*

```
Error message: 
Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (libruby.so.1.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/test/gems/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so) 

Exception class: 
LoadError
```

**Enviornment**

```
# ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-linux]

# rails -v
Rails 3.2.6

# gem -v
1.8.23

# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.34, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

#gem list
...
mysql2 (0.3.11)
...

#bundle show
...
mysql2 (0.3.11)
...

#vim database.yml

production:
 adapter: mysql2
 database: database_name
 host: localhost
 username: dbuser
 password: dbpwd
 encoding: utf8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369918/cant-run-my-server-in-rails-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-12-04/10369979#comment31045377_10369979) question solved my issue.

```
gem uninstall mysql2
bundle install
```