# Where is the Gemfile in Windows 7 located?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2, gemfile

i need some help at ruby on rails specially with ruby gems.

If i use the "rails generate scaffold something", I get always the failure:

"Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add 'gem' mysql2 to your Gemfile(Gem::LoadError)"

If i use the command "gem -list" mysql2(0.3.15) will show up in this list.

After some search i read([Install mysql adapter gem install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609985/please-install-mysql-adapter-gem-install-activerecord-mysql-adapter)) 
that i should edit the Gemfile and add gem 'mysql2', "~>0.3.15" instead of gem 'mysql2' in Gemfile.

So my problem is now where is this Gemfile located. I use ruby on Windows 7, and i installed Ruby with the "railsinstaller-2.2.2"

Regards, dot

Comment: You must have created a Rails project, in which you are calling `rails generate scaffold`... The `Gemfile` should be at the root directory or that rails project. If it isn't (for some crazy reason) I would recommend re-creating the rails project with `rails new`.

Comment: After changing the Gemfile, run `bundle install`.